# Prefilled Textarea Duplicated after Validation - PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a message that I need to prepopulate for a textarea. This message can be edited by users.

If there is a form validation error, the message appears to be duplicated each time that an error occurs.

```
<textarea name="comments" rows="20" style="width:99%;"><?=$fields['comments']?>TEXT  
 HERE</textarea>
```

I don't believe that this is an error due to the validation, but rather the field saving the content and adding it to the existing prepopulated message.

Is there a way that I can load the message and have users edit it without duplication?

I can provide any code necessary. I am currently using this code for validation:
https://github.com/benkeen/php_validation

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['senders_email'] = $_POST['senders_email'];
$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
$_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
$_SESSION['comments'] = $_POST['comments'];

//e-mail message text
$body=<<<_MSG_
Hello,

$comments

Sincerely,

$name
$address
$city
$state
_MSG_;
$text = strip_tags($body);

$errors = array();
$fields = array(); 
$success_message = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require_once("validation.php");

$rules = array(); // stores the validation rules

$rules[] = "required,name,Your <em>Name</em> is required.";   
$rules[] = "required,senders_email,Your <em>E-mail</em> is required.";
$rules[] = "valid_email,senders_email,Please enter a valid e-mail address."; 
$rules[] = "required,address,Your <em>Address</em> is required.";  

$errors = validateFields($_POST, $rules);

if (!empty($errors))
{
$fields = $_POST;
}

// no errors! redirect the user to the thankyou page (or whatever)
else
{
mail($to,$subject,$text,$headers);
header( "Location: thanks.php" );
}
}
?>
```

Comment: whats duplicated? where? when?

Comment: can you post your validateFields($_POST, $rules) method's code

Comment: The prepopulated text inside of the textarea is duplicated after a form error occurs.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "each time that an error occurs"? Each time = if you submit form with error you get 1 duplicate, you try again and you get 2 duplicates, 3rd time you get 4 duplicaes?

Comment: Exactly. Each time I hit submit and an error occurs the content is duplicated.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to ask one more thing, duplicated part is <?=$fields['comments']?> or TEXT HERE, or whole text?